# Start User Profile Synchronization on SharePoint 2010 standalone installation

Tags: user-profile, profile-sync

I recently created a SharePoint 2010 standalone VM with ADDS. As soon as I start User Profie Synchronization service, the service status shows starting and then stops in a minute.

Googling, I came across an MSDN article which says that user profile synchronization is not supported on standalone installation of SharePoint 2010.

So was wondering that is there any ways through which we can workaround this issue and get it working on SharePoint 2010 standalone VM.

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to start this service by Farm Administrator account. In my case - I change Service Account to Local Administrator (by this account I install SharePoint), who also been Farm Administrator.

Another way described here: [Forefront Identity Manager errors when starting the SharePoint 2010 User Profile Synchronization Service Application](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3913/forefront-identity-manager-errors-when-starting-the-sharepoint-2010-user-profile)

Comment: Thanks Vitaly, but what does it mean start the service by Farm Admin?
I am logged in as the Farm account (account used to install SP2010) and then also I get this error.
However I have created a seperate service account (SPServiceAcc) which owns all the service apps. So when I try to start the service, I am navigated to a page asking the credentials of my service account.
So do I need to change the service account to farm?

Comment: I create separate service account too, but for User Profile Sync, as I understand need more rights than just managed account, because its running Forefornt Identity Windows Service. Go to Security - Configure service accounts - and set to User Profile Sync Service your local admin account and reboot machine ;). This need help

Comment: I tried setting service account for User Profile Sync Service to mu local administrator and restarted the machine but it did not reflect when i attempt to start the service.
I then had to set my local admin account as my farm admin in Configure service accounts and then it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Just as you say - you cannot use the UPA in Standalone configuration. You need a server Farm setup. I wouldn't even try a workaround with UPA on standalone - enough trouble getting it rollin on a farm already :-)

Configuring a server farm does not take much more time or problems compared to a Standalone, esp if its a demo or dev box. Almost the opposite - since you spend time trying to fix things not supported.

Comment: Thanks Wictor. Actually I am running the VM on my laptop using the boot from VHD configuration, so having a farm setup in that case is not an option for me :-(.

Comment: You don't need a multiple servers to run a farm setup! Just so NOT select the Standalone option and install SQL Server (express/standard/developer...) b4 attempting to install SP

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip Wictor. I will try this out today!

Answer (score 0):

this can be configured in farm admins group policy. User sharepoint online instead.

Answer (score 0):

Accordign to the following article 
http://shareyourdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/user-profile-synchronization-service.html?showComment=1296151501971#c4216831443756978879

this feature is not exist in the Standalone installation