# User Profile Service will not Start

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service

When I provision the User Profile Service it will not start. I started with a clean install of SharePoint 2013 (Build Version: 15.0.4420.1017) on Windows Server 2012. Initially I used PowerShell to configure the UPS service application with an account other than the `SP_Farm`. Once I realized there was an issue, I deleted the existing service app.

I then reprovisioned it using the central admin UI and the farm account. The farm account was a member of the local administrators group. I rebooted the server and attempted to start the UPS. Experienced the same issue.

I rechecked that the Farm account had [the required permissions in AD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh296982.aspx). I stopped all SharePoint services and then then [deleted the FIM certificates](http://practicalsharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/01/quick-and-dirty-guide-to-recreating.html). I then rebooted the server and tried to start the service in Central Admin again. Same exact issues.

I then uninstalled SharePoint entirely and deleted all databases from the SQL Server. I set the Farm account as an SA on the server just in case. [I reinstalled SharePoint](http://www.slideshare.net/SPTechConSanFrancisco/how-to-install-sharepoint-2013-without-messing-it-up-by-todd-klindt-and-shane-young-stechcon), rebooted the server and ran the configuration scripts as per usual. Then I created the user profile service app using the Central Admin UI. I rebooted the server. I attempted to start the service from central admin. Same errors.

I deleted the UPS yet again. I added the [farm account to Domain Admins](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3913/forefront-identity-manager-errors-when-starting-the-sharepoint-2010-user-profile). I restarted the server again. At his point the Farm account is an SA on the SQL Server and a Domain Admin.  I reprovisioned the UPS. I attempted to start it. Same errors.

My next step will be to format the hard drive, reinstall the server OS, delete the databases, reinstall SharePoint and try everything over again.

Does anyone have a suggestion for what mistake I am making?

**UPDATE - Jan, 10, 2014**

We have done multiple rebuilds, searched AD for duplicate SPNs, possible duplicate CNs in AD, every possible rabbit hole has boon ferreted. All that we know for sure is that it's an error being thrown deep down in a SQL stored procedure. I am going to attempt the build in a clean lab with a new AD just to be sure that we can at least do that. But there has to be some sort of issue in our AD that is causing this.

**EDIT:**

Just to be clear regarding the common questions I have been asked:

1. The UPS was being run as the Farm Account. Initially this was not the case, though. The First time I reprovisioned the service it was the Farm account. So in every case except the initial failure, it was being run as the Farm account including the time I completely uninstalled SharePoint and reinstalled.
2. As I stated above, the Farm was and continues to be local admin.
3. It has log on locally rights. In fact, I logged on as the Farm account to the server to ensure this and to ensure that the default language was English.
4. As I explained above, I followed the guidance in the link given (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh296982.aspx) to ensure the Farm account had the required permissions and was a member of the required groups. This was done before I used the Farm account to deploy the UPS and was verified on two separate instances.
5. The Web Services App Pool is running.

**END EDIT**

Here are the errors. I have tried everything suggested in every link that Google has yielded to me. I even logged in as the Farm Account to ensure that its [default language was English](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65701/hostid-is-not-registered-when-starting-user-profile-synchronization-service/65988?noredirect=1#comment77251_65988).

**ILM Web Service Configuration**

```
ILM Certificate could not be created: netsh http error:netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:5726/ user=CTCT\sp_farm sddl=D:(A;;GA;;;S-1-5-21-836088835-2467000696-1087451681-4209)
```

**Forefront Identity Manager**

```
.Net SqlClient Data Provider: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Data.DataAccess.ProcessRequest(RequestType request)
```

**Forefront Identity Manager**

```
.Net SqlClient Data Provider: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 2.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Data.DataAccess.UpdateRequest(RequestType request, IEnumerable`1 updates)
```

**Forefront Identity Manager**

```
.Net SqlClient Data Provider: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 2.
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Utilities.ExceptionManager.ThrowException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Data.Exception.DataAccessExceptionManager.ThrowException(SqlException innerException)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Data.DataAccess.UpdateRequest(RequestType request, IEnumerable`1 updates)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.RequestDispatcher.UpdateRequestAndPersist(RequestType request)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.RequestDispatcher.DispatchRequest[ResponseBodyType](RequestType request, Guid requestIdentifier, Object redispatchSingleInstanceKey)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.RequestDispatcher.DispatchRequest[ResponseBodyType](RequestType request)
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.ResourceManagementService.Create(Message request)
```

Comment: what does your environment look like? farms/servers/SQL version/etc.? Also, what build of SharePoint 2013 are you installing?

Comment: 2 Server topology, SQL Server 2012 on Win server 2012 and the WFE is Server 2012 as well. I ensured the WFE had all the required updates including the so-called "Forgotten Prerequisites" http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=406

Comment: I'll check the build tomorrow. If I keep working on this tonight my wife may have to put me on a 72 hour psychological hold.

Comment: completely understood. Does the User Profile service have the necessary permission on the server (administrators) before provisioning? 1.You must run the UPA Service Instance as the Farm Account. 
2.Farm Account must be a local administrator of the machine running the UPA Service Instance during provisioning only. 
3.Farm Account must have Log on Locally rights. 
4.The Synchronization Connection Account must have Replicating Directory Changes.. 
5.Sharepoint webservices application pool started in IIS.

Comment: I had a similar problem on my development environment (WS2012), and the customer production environment (WS2008R2). I solved it using  Harbar's [Rational Guide to implementing SharePoint Server 2010 User Profile Application](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx). It works on both SharePoint Server 2013 Standard and Enterprise. Try the guide, and don't leave out any step!

Comment: At this point I am going to create a completely new VM and try again. I will be sure to read all of the suggested material thoroughly and update the question with any new information.

Comment: @Mike - I have added the build information to the question (15.0.4420.1017)

Comment: Take a look at this beautiful article by Spence Harbar: http://www.harbar.net/articles/fimportal.aspx

Comment: I don't believe that is applicable at all. That's about configuring the FIM portal with SharePoint 2013 which is not what I am doing. Is there a specific aspect of that article you believe might pertain to my issue?

Comment: I apologize I jumped the gun. Here are two articles about the UPS that should still be relevant to 2013.  http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have followed spences guide to the letter. Re deployed a fresh build, still no joy. I have installed the march CU with the autospinstaller, I might try a raw build and see.

Comment: We have this working now. It was a less than 3 minute difference on the time of a single domain controller. User Jeff Sacksteder will write up the complete answer and I'll accept it. And the Kerberos policy was still at the default of 5 minutes. No idea why this was the issue.

Comment: Is this issue related to SQL 2012 CU6? I noticed the same errors in my logs after applying the CU6. I'm still not able to recreate UPS.

Comment: All I know is that after the time skew between the servers was fixed, the service started with no problems.

Comment: When you changed the db server time and app server time? did you reconfigure the servers? and what steps did you follow to make User profile working again?

Comment: I am afraid this does not give an answer. You can comment once you attain 50 reputations.

Comment: spMahesh, as I mentioned above we simple corrected the time skew issue and it immediately allowed us to restart the service. The problem arose because we were syncing time from our parent company's domain controllers. We set the DCs to sync normally and the problem disappeared immediately after the time on both servers was in sync. It was almost like magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can occur if there is clock skew between SQL Server and the Web Front End.

In our case the time on the WFE was being set by a DC with the correct time, the time on the database server was being set by another domain controller with a -3 minute difference.