# Share Point 2013 Product configuration fails at 9 step

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Below is the complete error message I got while product configuration.

> Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: One or
>   more types failed to load. Please refer to the upgrade log for more
>   details.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.LoadUpgradeActions()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.get_ActionsInternal()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUtility.GetLatestTargetSchemaVersionBeforeMajorVersion(Type
>   typeActionSequence, Int32 majorVer)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPSiteSequence.get_PreviousTargetSchemaVersion()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.PopulateSequencesTable(StringBuilder
>   sqlstr, Boolean siteSequence)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ConstructSiteNeedsUpgradeQuery(Guid
>   siteId)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.GetSiteNeedsUpgrade(SPUpgradeSession
>   session, SPContentDatabase database, Dictionary`2&
>   dictSitesNeedUpgrade, Dictionary`2& dictSitesNeedFeatureUpgrade)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.AddNextLevelObjects()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root,
>   Boolean bRecursing, SPDelegateManager delegateManager)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root,
>   SPDelegateManager delegateManager)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object
>   o, Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object
>   o, Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object
>   o, Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object
>   o, Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerProductInfo.DetectLocalUpgradeStatus()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerProductInfo.DetectLocalProductVersions(SPProductVersions
>   prodVer)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerProductInfo.UpdateProductInfoInDatabase(Guid
>   serverGuid)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.FinalizeTask.Run()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Comment: On which system you are configuring the SharePoint Enterprise ?

Can you provide the details ?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 is the application server and Sql server 2014 is database server.

Comment: which service pack are you trying to install?

Comment: Try following [This Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262243.aspx).

It shows the prerequisites and Installation process.

Comment: I have installed SharePoint 2013 some days back. Please check this link, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/152905/user-profile-synchronization-service-is-not-starting
After doing this I tried product activation and now I am getting error.

Comment: You'll get an error.log file in 15 hive logs. Sort by date modified. Can you check that file for details?

Comment: Have you installed MS Office in machine on which you are trying to run configuration wizard?

Comment: @Hardi, No MS Office installation

Answer (score 1):

See [This](http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2014/03/sharepoint-2013-product-configuration.html)

1. Clear the Cache.ini
2. Go to Location C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config
3. Now we can able to see the GUID’s
4. In Right hand side Corner top Search like cache.ini
5. Open the cache.ini and reset the value to 1
6. Run the Command stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
7. After that finally run

   Psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force

You can Even See [this Solution](http://alstechtips.blogspot.in/2014/05/sharepoint-2013-product-configuration.html)

It Says :

1. Delete the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard dialog.  Terminate the process of necessary to remove it.
2. Open the Services.msc panel, and then look for the SharePoint Timer Service.
3. Stop this service.
4. Open Windows Explorer, and then navigate to the cache folder at: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config.
5. Look for the most recent cache folder, and then open it.
6. Delete all files in this folder EXCEPT cache.ini.
7. Open the cache.ini file in a text editor, and then randomly modify the number, but keep it at the same number of digits.
8. Save the cache.ini file.
9. Start the SharePoint Timer Service.
10. Open a command prompt as Administrator.
11. Run the following command: Psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force
12. Check the Upgrade Status.

Comment: Vishwas, really thanks for your reply. I tried you both solution you provided but none worked for me.

Comment: okay, 

will try getting some other solution for you and edit my answer back

Answer (score 0):

Please use `psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace v2v -passphrase <passphrase> -wait`
command in SharePoint Management Shell.

Check that the windows sharepoint services are started and add the service account in

> - IIS_IUSRS
> - WSS_ADMIN_WPG
> - WSS_WPG

Comment: what is value of <passphrase> in above command?

Comment: Which you have specified after your configuration database settings and enter the DOMAIN\sp_farm account credentials.

Comment: Check Step 12 in http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14209.sharepoint-2013-installation-step-by-step.aspx

Comment: Hi, I used <passphrase> but getting error "The inplace parameter specified with the upgrade command is invalid."

Comment: One more thing, I dont see "IIS_WPG" group in my application server.

Comment: Which IIS version do you have? It is already available in IIS 7 but It is now called the IIS_IUSRS.

Comment: ohoo...I have IIS_IUSERS

Comment: is the solutions working for you?

Comment: No,  I used <passphrase> but getting error "The inplace parameter specified with the upgrade command is invalid.