# SharePoint 2013 user profile sync service stuck on starting after db restore

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, managed-metadata

I have restored my managed metadata db and user profile db's on a new SharePoint 2013 farm with a SQL 2012 server. I recreated both service applications with the restored db's (created a new sync db otherwise I can't start the sync service). The managed metadata and user profile service application are working. No errors what so ever.

I now try to start the "User Profile Synchronization Service" This process takes a while but ends and the service is still stopped. During this time it is stuck in the famous starting state.

I get the following errors in the ULS
Looks like something in combination with the managed metadata service :

```
ILM Configuration: Setting policy for service account   
ILM Configuration: Configuring database 
ILM Configuration: Re-starting mms service  
ILM Configuration: Checking mms service 
ILM Configuration: Error 'ERR_START_SERVICE'.   
UserProfileApplication.SynchronizeMIIS: Failed to configure MIIS post database, will attempt during next rerun. Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: ERR_START_SERVICE     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.Synchronization.ILMPostSetupConfiguration.ValidateConfigurationResult(UInt32 result)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.SetupSynchronizationService(ProfileSynchronizationServiceInstance profileSyncInstance).   
UserProfileApplication.SynchronizeMIIS: End setup for 'User Profile Service Application'.ILM Configuration: Changing service account credentials
```

I have created multiple SharePoint 2013 farms in the past so all the requirements needed for starting the "User Profile Synchronization Service" are correct. All permissions etc.. are set.

Any ideas?

Regards Danny

Comment: I have tried the same but now creating a new managed metadata and ups application with new databases. So a clean setup. Even then I get the same error in my ULS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a dependency in the FIM service. The solution provided here

http://fangdahai.blogspot.nl/2017/01/resolved-failed-to-configure-miis-post.html

Fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you move UserProfileDatabases to a new SharePoint-Installation, you also have to move the Microsoft Identity Integration Server Key (MIIS) encryption key.

The whole process is very well described in [this blog](http://blog.mfoltyn.cz/2014/10/user-profile-migration-from-sharepoint-2010-to-2013/). It shows a move from SP2010 to SP2013 but also applies if you copy on the same version.

Comment: In the export key section it states:
Note: If you do not want to migrate Sync database, then exporting (and later importing) of encryption key is not required.
I am using a new Sync database. So I don't need this step

Comment: Sorry, didn't read all details in your question. Added a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have installed "SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Native Client". You might have installed newer versions. The old one is a [SharePoint 2013 Prerequisite](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2012/12/26/install-and-download-sharepoint-2013-prerequisites-offline-manually/)

Maybe these articles also help:

[ERR_config_Db while starting the UPA Synchronization service in SharePoint 2010/2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2015/06/16/err_config_db-while-starting-the-upa-synchronization-service-in-sharepoint-20102013/)

[Provisioning User Profile Service - Will not start](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98076/provisioning-user-profile-service-will-not-start)

Comment: I am using a SQL server 2012 and SharePoint 2013 SP1 and feb 2017 CU. Should I still install this?

Comment: I just checked in programs and features and the 2008R2 native client is already installed. When I run the installer it says that its already installed.